# swift 2 PHP cannot upload fully string to mysql

Tags: php, facebook, swift2

The facebook userPic URL i can print it fully in console, but cannot upload it fully to databse. I cannot find the problem. :(

swift:

```
    let imageURL = self.UserInfor.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as! String
    
    print("imageURL = \(imageURL)") 

   //fully URL: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xal1/v/t1.0-1/12316561_118660575171228_1608374168143089865_n.jpg?oh=80b4cea8fb35c512c0b228e5b28c39ec&oe=5782D22C     
  
    
    
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "myphp.php")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    
    let bodydata = "FaceBookPic=\(imageURL)&facebook_id=\(self.UserInfor.objectForKey("id") as! String)"
 //it will be https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xal1/v/t1.0-1/12316561_118660575171228_1608374168143089865_n.jpg?oh=80b4cea8fb35c512c0b228e5b28c39ec  
//which missing "&oe=5782D22C"
    request.HTTPBody = bodydata.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

myphp.php:

```
$facebook_id = ($_POST["facebook_id"]);
$facebook_pic = ($_POST["FaceBookPic"]);
$sql =  "INSERT INTO facebookUser (facebook_id, userPic) VALUES ('" .
            $facebook_id."', '".$facebook_pic ."' )";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

why the picURl is not a fully URL?

**update**

i find that it is not the swift problem because:

```
  let imageURL = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xal1/v/t1.0-1/12316561_118660575171228_1608374168143089865_n.jpg?oh=80b4cea8fb35c512c0b228e5b28c39ec&oe=5782D22C"

// it also will upload " https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xal1/v/t1.0-1/12316561_118660575171228_1608374168143089865_n.jpg?oh=80b4cea8fb35c512c0b228e5b28c39ec"  
//which missing "&oe=5782D22C"
```

I think it should be PHP problem.

The data type of userPic is varchar(255).

**update 2 **

I have tried editing  myPHP to:

```
 $facebook_pic = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xal1/v/t1.0-1/12316561_118660575171228_1608374168143089865_n.jpg?oh=80b4cea8fb35c512c0b228e5b28c39ec&oe=5782D22C";
```

and it work! I guess the problem will be the connection between swift and PHP `$facebook_pic = ($_POST["FaceBookPic"]);`. Isn't that having any string limited checking?

Comment: i just want to ask why` "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net...&oe=5782D22C"`  will be changed to  ` " https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/...39ec"`  in the connecting  in swift and PHP

Comment: You should not store Facebook CDN URLs for long(er)-time use anyway – they are to be considered “transient”, meaning they will change over time, and may be different to begin with depending on in whose name (access token) they were requested with. Use the redirect URL Facebook provides, if showing the current profile picture is the intended purpose here.